# nginx not work when access by domain from another computer

Tags: nginx, webserver

On my LAN network, I have a server installed with nginx with port 80 and a Website port 1111. My network has a DNS server, a domain name website.com points to this server.

I access my website from another computer  by link website.com:1111 and the website is accessible. But when I access website.com or server IP address to access nginx my browser tells me ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT, If I access that domain from server then nginx is oke.

Why can't nginx serve my request if I access it from another computer  by IP address/domain?

This is my nginx config.

[image]